# 2D Plotting in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to draw a boundary on a x-y plane with the followings given:

a) a matrix called 'decision_region' with size(41,41), filled with either 1 or 0. Those 1's and 0's are separated by a boundary which is y =x.

That is for decision_region(i,j), with positions that satisfied `i > j`, are all 1's.

b) x, and y array with size(1,41).

I know how to use `surf(x,y,decision_region)` to create a surface plot. But how can I get a `y = x` plot in a x-y plane?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but from what I understand

```
hold on
plot(x, y)
```

should overlay the desired boundary over the surface.